# python: how to import nested package?

Tags: python, import

I have a package named myscrapy, the directory structure is:

```
+ spider-common
--+ myscrapy
----+ basespiders
------+ __init__.py
------+ mod.py
--+ __init__.py
--+ mod.py
```

And I have an enviroment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/spider-common
```

This is success:

```
from myscrapy import mod
```

But it failed:

```
from myscrapy.basespiders import mod
```

ImportError: No module named myscrapy.basespiders

why?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your diagram. Are the `__init__.py` and `mod.py` files at the bottom in the top-level `spider-common` folder, or in the `myscrappy` subfolder? The indentation level suggests the top level, but that doesn't match the `from myscrappy import mod` line you say does work, and an `__init__.py` file at top level is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import command treads every folder only as a package (which is importable), when a certain structure is present (see [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)).
You have to place a `__init__.py` file (could be a blank one) in every subdirectory you import.